# Python: What do double parenthesis do?

Tags: python, syntax, parentheses

Can anyone tell me why the parenthesis are doubled here?

```
self.__items.append((module, item))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's passing the tuple `(module, item)` to the function as a single argument.  Without the extra parens, it would pass `module` and `item` as separate arguments.

Comment: All the answers provided so far should prove helpful to the OP.  I personally like this one best because it does NOT set off the pedant alarm regarding tuple creation.  Well done!

Comment: @JohnY peoples who knew that it creates a tuple obviously wouldn't come up here with the question.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: I don't think you understood my comment. The "pedant alarm" I was referring to is the whole "tuples are created by commas, not parentheses" thing. Tuple pedants love to bring attention to this point, and seem to do so at every opportunity. Of course, it's a true point; but to me, it's overly technical, especially as an explanation to a beginner. What I like about this answer is that it is phrased in a way that *doesn't* emphasize this point.

Comment: @JohnY oh, well, actually I missed the *tuple* word when I first read this answer, so I was like «Eh? Why are the braces makes a single argument?». Anyway, I'm somewhat inexperienced with Python, and despite that I like the technical explanation below about the comma making a tuple.

Answer (score 15):

The inner parenthesis create a [tuple](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

```
>>> type(('a', 'b'))
<type 'tuple'>
```

Technically, tuples can be created without parenthesis:

```
>>> 'a', 'b'
('a', 'b')
```

But sometimes they need parenthesis:

```
>>> 'a', 'b' + 'c', 'd'
('a', 'bc', 'd')
>>> ('a', 'b') + ('c', 'd')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

In your case, they need parenthesis to distinguish the tuple from the comma-separated arguments to a function. For example:

```
>>> def takes_one_arg(x):
...     return x
... 
>>> takes_one_arg('a', 'b')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: takes_one_arg() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
>>> takes_one_arg(('a', 'b'))
('a', 'b')
```

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly the same as saying:

```
parameter = (module, item)
self.__items.append(parameter)
```

I.e. the inner parens are first creating a tuple before the tuple is used as the single argument to `append()`.

Comment: except you do NOT need the parens around the tuple in your example... parameter = module, item is just fine.